# Calculate the origin of a sphere from a number of randomly placed points on the surface

Tags: geometry

My problem is to calculate the origin of a ball from some motion capture data which is random markers on the surface of the ball that may or may not be visible in any frame. I have from 0-5 markers visible in any frame.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can't calculate it exactly if there are only some random points. Also you don't say what information the points have.

Comment: Given a pair of points, compute the equation of the plane that bisects them and is perpendicular. Now do this for all the pairs of markers in your set, and see if you can solve the resulting system of equations uniquely. Usually, you will be able to do this if you have four points on the sphere, but I'm not sure if you can always do it.

Comment: Each marker has x,y,z basic spacial position in a 3d space.  There is also time-series frames before and after with a known sampling rate. However the velocity of the object will change based on impacts, gravity etc.

Comment: Do you have the radius of the ball?

Comment: Yes, I have the ball radius. Standard soccer ball.

Answer (score 1):

If $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4$ are four points on the sphere and $c$ is the centre,
for each $i$ and $j$ you have $0 = (p_i - c)\cdot (p_i - c) - (p_j - c) \cdot (p_j - c) = p_i \cdot p_i - p_j \cdot p_j + c \cdot (p_j - p_i)$.  This system of linear equations in $c$ determines $c$ unless there is some nonzero vector $x$ with $x \cdot (p_i - p_j) = 0$ for all $i,j$.  But that would mean all $p_i$ are in the same plane.  Thus: as long as you have four non-coplanar points visible, you can determine the position of the centre.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the radius of the ball and points $x$, $y$ and $z$ on the surface of the ball, if you have more than two points, you just need to find the point equidistant from each point. If we say the centre is at point $(a, b, c)$ then you have equations
$$
(x_i-a)^2+(y_i-b)^2+(z_i-c)^2=r^2.
$$
where $i$ is one of the points.

You then just need to rearrange these to eliminate $a$, $b$, and $c$, for example
$$
c = z_i - \sqrt{r^2-(x_i-a)^2-(y_i-b)^2}
$$
for one of the $i$'s, substitute it in, and so on, until you have all the values.

This provides an exact solution for 3 points. If you only have two points then the set of solutions is a circle. If you only have one point the set of solutions is a sphere.

Comment: Hi Suzu, Three points will only give a triangle, doesn't that mean there will be two possible solutions? If they were the three corners of a triangular pyramid, the pyramid could either point upward or downward and still be equidistant from the three points.  As Robert said above, if the points are co-planar then the origin of the ball could be in either direction.  Three points always form a plane.

Comment: @Duncan - yes you are right, there will be two points.